# cannot display products by map in jsx components

Tags: reactjs

I wanna display my products by using map function but i have the error: "*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'products')*". Is there anything wrong with my codes? can anyone help me to find out? Thank you so much!

This is my sandbox link:https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-shop-cart-oqf77?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Please post the code in the question using a stack snippet: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an array out of `props.products`, like so:

```
var products = Array.from(props.products);
```

then will be able to use `products.map()` function

working example on: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-shop-cart-forked-f3jro?file=/src/components/Products.js)

Comment: Thank you so much! btw, can i ask you the same prbl in the same project, how can i declare a variable of "count" to use in the Filter component cause my codes don't work again...Code link: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-shop-cart-forked-tlpek?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @naha you're welcome, of course! this time count is a number (not an array), so just props.count will work fine. [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-shop-cart-forked-5u0vu?file=/src/components/Filter.js)

Comment: @naha Don't forget to upvote and accept the best answer ;)

Comment: Why do you remove this from {this.props.count} tho?

Comment: @naha I didn't get what you mean, please explain more